# Fragments - How to

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have three fragments in  two activities;fragmentA in activityA and fragmentB,fragmentC in activityB.when i click  a button in fragmentA i want to go specifically to fragmentB (not fragment c) in activityB. please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in OnCreateView of Fragment A:

```
Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry,there is a small change in my question.please look into it.i hope you will help me agin..

Comment: So, you want to go to fragment B which is inside the Activity B. You just need start to that activity.

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class); startActivity(intent);